# Where to ask questions about Ancient Astronaut Theories?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Recently I have come across these studies and have a lot to discuss about it. But I'm not sure which community is right to ask questions about it. Please suggest me the communities and/or tags if anything is already there.

Sample questions would be "Is it possible that different kinds of aliens have ruled the world?" or "Why mystical places around the world have some relation with Orion belt?"

Comment: Maybe [skeptics.se]? Hard to know without more specifics. Can you post a sample question you'd like to ask?

Comment: It would be great if it had a separate tag. It is a vast subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would agree with [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/).  Some might argue that it should go in [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/), though.

Comment: Do _absolutely_ read their [advice for new users](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users).